# Bash script to login to website and download file

Tags: linux, bash

I am a bit stuck with my bash script.  I need it to login to a website which https based... it needs to login with a username and password and then it needs to locate a particular link, the text of the link is always the same but the location it points to changes, it needs to grab that location and download it with wget.

Anhbody have any tips, i need it to be portable so i prefer not to rely on external programs..

Thank you

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Bash does not have SSL support, you have to use *some* external program, or hack in SSL to Bash itself (hardly more than a theoretical option).

Answer (score 4):

`bash` is not ideal for those kind of tasks. Although you can try something like:

```
curl --user name:password https://www.example.com/
```

But if you need to find a link on the page, you can try:

```
curl --user name:password https://www.example.com/ | grep WHAT_EVER_IDENTIFIES_LINK
```

Then get it's output via `curl` again.

But I would recommend something like [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for the task. There are simillar libraries for python and Ruby, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This code works to login to the website, but I am not sure how to proceed to identify the link and wget it...

```
#!/bin/bash

#REQUIRED PARAMS
username=""
password=""

#EXTRA OPTIONS
uagent="Mozilla/5.0" #user agent (fake a browser)
sleeptime=0 #add pause between requests

touch "cookie.txt" #create a temp. cookie file

#INITIAL PAGE
echo "[+] Fetching" && sleep $sleeptime
initpage=`curl -s -b "cookie.txt" -c "cookie.txt" -L --sslv3 -A "$uagent"                "https://ny2.free2surfvpn.com/?src=connect"`
token=`echo "$initpage" | grep "authenticity_token" | sed -e 's/.*value="//' | sed -e   's/" \/>.*//'`

#LOGIN
echo "[+] Submitting the login form..." && sleep $sleeptime
loginpage=`curl -s -b "cookie.txt" -c "cookie.txt" -L --sslv3 -A "$uagent" -d     "authenticity_token=$token&username=$username&password=$password"     "https://mobile.twitter.com/session"`

#HOME PAGE
echo "[+] Getting page" && sleep $sleeptime
homepage=`curl -s -b "cookie.txt" -c "cookie.txt" -L -A "$uagent"     "https://ny2.free2surfvpn.com/?src=connect"`

rm "cookie.txt"
```